# Proof for Cauchy's Definition of Centre of Curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Cauchy defined the center of curvature as the intersection point of normals drawn to two infinitely close points on a curve. Is there any way to prove this?
I am unable to get a starting point for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you are dealing with biregular plane curve $\gamma=(x,y)\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with unit speed.  The normal line at $\gamma(0)=(x_0,y_0)$ is (self-explanary notation)
$$
(\dot x_0,\dot y_0)\cdot(x,y)=x_0\dot x_0+y_0\dot y_0
$$
and normal line at $\gamma(h)$ is
$$
(\dot x_h,\dot y_h)\cdot(x,y)=x_h\dot x_h+y_h\dot y_h
$$
so their intersection is
$$
(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+(-\dot y_0,\dot x_0)\lambda
$$
where
$$
\lambda=\frac{(x_h-x_0)\dot x_h+(y_h-y_0)\dot y_h}{(-\dot y_0,\dot x_0)\cdot(\dot x_h,\dot y_h)}.
$$
But the numerator is $h(\dot x_0^2+\dot y_0^2)+o(h)=h+o(h)$ and the denominator is $h(\dot x_0\ddot y_0-\ddot x_0\dot y_0)+o(h)$, so $\lambda$ agrees with the (signed) radius of curvature in the limit and you recover the formula for the center of curvature.

Comment: Can you lead me to a source where I can check out how the point of intersection is calculated?

Comment: This should be an easy exercise to fill in.  For example, you can solve the pair of simultaneous linear equations in two variables, or you can parametrize one line and substitute into the other.